# Get datasource of child grid in Kendo using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I have a master detail grid in kendo Grid and I am using the angular version of the Kendo Grid.

I have added a custom button for adding a new record in each row of the grid and the records is added below the row on which the button is clicked.

Below is the code that is working.

**Button Template**

```
<img src='images/save.png' ng-click='onClick()'
 class='k-grid-add' title='Add new record' alt='Create'/>
```

**The click function**

```
$scope.onClick = function ()
{               
    var grid = $scope.grid;    
    var sel = grid.select();    
    var item = grid.dataItem(sel);    
    var index = grid.dataSource.indexOf(item);
    grid.dataSource.insert(index + 1, {});
}
```

This part is working fine. Now the problem is that I need similar button in each row in the child grid too. But I don't know how to get the dataSource of the child grid in angular. I believe if I can get the child grid then the above code could be used to add a new row using the index.

Thanks for your time, Feel free to ask if any other information is required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best approach but I got it working by using the following function on the click of the add button in the child grid row.

```
$scope.commomAddClick = function ($event) {
    var childGrid = $($event.currentTarget).closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var sel = childGrid.select();
    var item = childGrid.dataItem(sel);
    var index = childGrid.dataSource.indexOf(item);
    childGrid.dataSource.insert(index + 1, {});
};
```

In the add button I have wired the click event as

```
ng-click='commomAddClick($event)'
```